# Postgres How to import CSV ignoring a column id is bigserial

Tags: postgresql, import, cmdline-args

I have a CSV which contains column names and data, but does not have the column ID.
When I import my data via this command line:

```
type "..\MyCSVtoImport.csv" | "..\psql.exe" -h MyServerPostgres -p 5432 -U "MyUser" -c " COPY mytable FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER; " MyBase
```

I still have this error : ERROR:  missing data for column "id"

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you appending to the table or creating new?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a column list with `COPY`:

```
COPY mytable (col1, col2, ...) FROM STDIN;
```

Here you simply list all columns *except* `id`.

Comment: thk,
I have over 200 columns, is there a way to say except id

Comment: No, unfortunately not. You could query `information_schema.columns` and construct the SQL statement programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution:

```
CREATE mytable_import AS SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 0;
ALTER TABLE mytable_import DROP COLUMN id;

--COPY to mytable_import

INSERT INTO mytable SELECT nextval('mytable_id_seq') AS id, * FROM mytable_import;
```

Substitute actual sequence name into `nextval`. Also this may need tweaking depending on whether you are appending or starting with empty `mytable`. In appending an `ON CONFLICT` clause maybe needed.